# Hide the Wizard Step Title page in SAPUI5

Tags: html, css, sapui5, wizard

I am having a requirement for **SAPUI5** app to hide the title in wizard step although it has to be there in title bar. I have highlighted that in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I have used sap.m.Wizard layout but as a part of standard layout, I am getting the title in this way. If I remove the title, I am getting just 1, 2, 3. My requirement is that I need to remove "1.Introduction" also in top the Introduction text has to be there.

Comment: I have gone through all the related questions but still didnt get this issue resolved. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a standalone application, you can extend the control "sap.m.WizardStep" as a solution.

**Screenshots of extending the control and using it in the app** :

[Creating the files for extending WizardStep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlgZ.jpg)

[WizardStep.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjOnZ.jpg)

[WizardStepRenderer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJUnc.jpg)

[Using the extended control in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ugVm.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QtIS.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is it possible for you to share the code so that I can try it myself looking into that?

Comment: Download the code using the following link and make changes as per the screenshots shown above.                                                                                             https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Wizard/code

Comment: Hi Stan, I followed the steps by downloading the code but seems like there is an issue with render object Caused by: TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined. Anything else I need to add?